# How to remove elements from applied filters on click of cross option? - Reactjs/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React Demo Project . Here is the [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7p1mjj7q6)

I have created filters using two columns. Now whatever filter I chose is displayed in the top part of the page. Now I can remove filter by cancelling the drop-down. But I also want to remove filter from the top area where the filter is displayed. As you can see there is a cross option in applied filter top div. When I click on any cross option that div should be removed and also the corresponding drop-down should be removed.

[image: Screen]

This is my code for the entire page

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { makeData } from "./Utils";

import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

 import jsondata from "./sample";

 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  // data: makeData(),
  data: jsondata,
  filtered: [],
  firstNameselect: [],
  lastNameselect: []
};
this.uniqueOptions = this.uniqueOptions.bind(this);
this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
 }

   onFilteredChangeCustom(value, accessor) {
console.log("accessor typeof " + typeof accessor);
console.log("The value is " + value);
let filtered = this.state.filtered;
console.log("the filtered items" + JSON.stringify(this.state.filtered));
let insertNewFilter = 1;

if (filtered.length) {
  console.log("filtered.length " + filtered.length);
  filtered.forEach((filter, i) => {
    if (filter["id"] === accessor) {
      if (value === "" || !value.length) filtered.splice(i, 1);
      else filter["value"] = value;

      insertNewFilter = 0;
    }
  });
}

if (insertNewFilter) {
  filtered.push({ id: accessor, value: value });
}

this.setState({ filtered: filtered });

console.log("this.state.filtered " + JSON.stringify(this.state.filtered));
  }

 uniqueOptions = (objectsArray, objectKey) => {
var a = objectsArray.map((o, i) => {
  return o[objectKey];
});

return a.filter(function(i, index) {
  return a.indexOf(i) >= index;
   });
  };

 handleFilter(item) {
console.log("Inside enter handleFilter");
console.log("console.log - > item.target.value " + item.target.value);
  }

  render() {
const { data } = this.state;
const a = this.state.filtered;

return (
  <div>
    <div className="applied-filter">
      {this.state.filtered.length > 0 && (
        <div className="applied-filter-text">Applied filters :</div>
      )}
      {a.map((obj, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="elliptical-applied-filter" key={key}>
            {obj.id}: {obj.value.join(",\u00A0")}
            {"\u00A0"}
            <div
              className="elliptical-applied-filter-cross"
              onClick={this.handleFilter}
            >
              <input
                type="image"
                id="cross-icon"
                src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/126/126497.png"
                alt="close"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Select FirstName :{" "}
    <Select
      style={{ width: "50%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
      onChange={entry => {
        this.setState(
          {
            firstNameselect: entry
          },
          () => {
            console.log(
              "this.state.firstNameselect " +
                JSON.stringify(this.state.firstNameselect)
            );
          }
        );
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
          entry.map(o => {
            return o.value;
          }),
          "firstName"
        );
      }}
      value={this.state.firstNameselect}
      multi={true}
      options={this.uniqueOptions(this.state.data, "firstName").map(
        (name, i) => {
          return { id: i, value: name, label: name };
        }
      )}
    />
    Select LastName :{" "}
    <Select
      style={{ width: "50%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
      onChange={entry => {
        this.setState(
          {
            lastNameselect: entry
          },
          () => {
            console.log(
              "this.state.lastNameselect " +
                JSON.stringify(this.state.lastNameselect)
            );
          }
        );
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
          entry.map(o => {
            return o.value;
          }),
          "lastName"
        );
      }}
      value={this.state.lastNameselect}
      multi={true}
      options={this.uniqueOptions(this.state.data, "lastName").map(
        (name, i) => {
          return { id: i, value: name, label: name };
        }
      )}
    />
    <ReactTable
      data={data}
      filtered={this.state.filtered}
      onFilteredChange={(filtered, column, value) => {
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(value, column.id || column.accessor);
      }}
      defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
        const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
        if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
          return row[id] !== undefined
            ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id]) > -1
            : true;
        } else {
          return row[id] !== undefined
            ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
            : true;
        }
      }}
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "Name",
          columns: [
            {
              Header: "First Name",
              accessor: "firstName"
            },
            {
              Header: "Last Name",
              id: "lastName",
              accessor: d => d.lastName
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Header: "Info",
          columns: [
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]}
      defaultPageSize={10}
      className="-striped -highlight"
    />
    <br />
  </div>
);
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Kindly check this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7p1mjj7q6) to see what I am trying to achieve.

When the cross icon lastName elliptical div is clicked this.state.lastNameselect should be blank and the corresponding sub object from this.state.filtered should also be removed

Similarly when the cross icon firstName elliptical div is clicked this.state.firstNameselect should be blank and the corresponding sub object from this.state.filtered should also be removed.

How can I achieve this functionality ? Kindly help. I need a generic solution. Now I have 2 drop-down, in future I will have many more.
 For example if we click the cross icon of last name the last name entry should be set to blank. The firstname should stay as it is. Same will happen for the click icon of the firstname

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please update your question with a [mcve] (note the **minimal**) demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Please remove images, add essential parts of the code and add expected output

Comment: Just to make things clear. When you click on the `close` icon, all the elements should be removed, right?

Comment: @Thinker No if we click the cross icon of last name the last name entry should be set to blank. The firstname should stay as it is

Answer (score 0):

You need add `handleFilter` change statement as you already have all the values, you can just pass it to the event and use it to filter it, I tried to make it generic for both firstname and lastname. this removes the entries from the state and respond with the removed one.

check this

```
  handleFilter(item) {
    var itemName =
      item.id === "firstName" ? "firstNameselect" : "lastNameselect";
    console.log(item);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [itemName]: this.state.firstNameselect.filter(
        a => item.value.indexOf(a.value) < 0
      ),
      filtered: this.state.filtered.filter(a => {
        if (item.id === a.id) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    });
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymnx7kqwj)

Comment: can you make the variable naming convention more generic.  Suppose when I have 10 to 12 drop-down instead of 2. Then I will have more fields, ageselect, cityselect, so on

Comment: Can you make this line more generic so that I can accommodate multiple drop-down in future
      item.id === "firstName" ? "firstNameselect" : "lastNameselect";

Comment: @tommy123 yes but for that you need to change your state little bit

Comment: @tommy123 check my demo link you will get it now

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

This is the steps done in `removeFilter` function:

1. I am passing the array where the user clicks the close icon and the name (`firstNameselect` or `secondNameselect`) of the field in the `removeFilter`
2. Then, I am finding the index of the passed array in the `filtered` array in `this.state` and remove the array using the index by the `splice` method.
3. Then I empty the array (`firstNameselect` or `secondNameselect`) for the dropdown values using `[array]: []`

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { makeData } from "./Utils";

import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

import jsondata from "./sample";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  // data: makeData(),
  data: jsondata,
  filtered: [],
  firstNameselect: [],
  lastNameselect: []
};
this.uniqueOptions = this.uniqueOptions.bind(this);
this.removeFilter = this.removeFilter.bind(this);
  }

  removeFilter = (obj, array) => {
let { filtered } = this.state;
let getIndex = -1;
filtered.map((item, index) => {
  if (item.id === obj.id) {
    getIndex = index;
  }
});
filtered.splice(getIndex, 1);
this.setState({
  filtered,
  [array]: []
});
  };

  onFilteredChangeCustom(value, accessor) {
let filtered = this.state.filtered;
let insertNewFilter = 1;

if (filtered.length) {
  filtered.forEach((filter, i) => {
    if (filter["id"] === accessor) {
      if (value === "" || !value.length) filtered.splice(i, 1);
      else filter["value"] = value;

      insertNewFilter = 0;
    }
  });
}

if (insertNewFilter) {
  filtered.push({ id: accessor, value: value });
}
this.setState({ filtered: filtered });
  }

  uniqueOptions = (objectsArray, objectKey) => {
var a = objectsArray.map((o, i) => {
  return o[objectKey];
});

return a.filter(function(i, index) {
  return a.indexOf(i) >= index;
});
  };

  render() {
const { data } = this.state;
const a = this.state.filtered;

return (
  <div>
    <div className="applied-filter">
      {this.state.filtered.length > 0 && (
        <div className="applied-filter-text">Applied filters :</div>
      )}
      {a.map((obj, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="elliptical-applied-filter" key={key}>
            {obj.id}: {obj.value.join(",\u00A0")}
            {"\u00A0"}
            <div className="elliptical-applied-filter-cross">
              <input
                type="image"
                id="cross-icon"
                src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/126/126497.png"
                alt="close"
                onClick={() => this.removeFilter(obj, `${obj.id}select`)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Select FirstName :{" "}
    <Select
      style={{ width: "50%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
      onChange={entry => {
        this.setState(
          {
            firstNameselect: entry
          },
          () => {
            console.log(
              "this.state.firstNameselect " +
                JSON.stringify(this.state.firstNameselect)
            );
          }
        );
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
          entry.map(o => {
            return o.value;
          }),
          "firstName"
        );
      }}
      value={this.state.firstNameselect}
      multi={true}
      options={this.uniqueOptions(this.state.data, "firstName").map(
        (name, i) => {
          return { id: i, value: name, label: name };
        }
      )}
    />
    Select LastName :{" "}
    <Select
      style={{ width: "50%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
      onChange={entry => {
        this.setState(
          {
            lastNameselect: entry
          },
          () => {
            console.log(
              "this.state.lastNameselect " +
                JSON.stringify(this.state.lastNameselect)
            );
          }
        );
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
          entry.map(o => {
            return o.value;
          }),
          "lastName"
        );
      }}
      value={this.state.lastNameselect}
      multi={true}
      options={this.uniqueOptions(this.state.data, "lastName").map(
        (name, i) => {
          return { id: i, value: name, label: name };
        }
      )}
    />
    <ReactTable
      data={data}
      filtered={this.state.filtered}
      onFilteredChange={(filtered, column, value) => {
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(value, column.id || column.accessor);
      }}
      defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
        const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
        if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
          return row[id] !== undefined
            ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id]) > -1
            : true;
        } else {
          return row[id] !== undefined
            ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
            : true;
        }
      }}
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "Name",
          columns: [
            {
              Header: "First Name",
              accessor: "firstName"
            },
            {
              Header: "Last Name",
              id: "lastName",
              accessor: d => d.lastName
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Header: "Info",
          columns: [
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]}
      defaultPageSize={10}
      className="-striped -highlight"
    />
    <br />
  </div>
);
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn41qlnn2m)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you help me to understand setstate array in remove filter function

Comment: Why you have added brackets while setting state of array - [] this bracket

Comment: @tommy123 since the `key` is a dynamic one, we need to enclose the key in [], else if I do like `array: []`, it will see for the `array` key in the `state` instead of the dynamic value (`firstNameselect` or `secondNameselect` in our case).

Comment: Thinker, I am increasing no of drop-downs to 10 or 12. If everything works fine, I will upvote your answer and mark it as correct. It is working fine for two Drop down